# Use the native arrow icon with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there any system icon or any other method to use a native arrow iCon with xcode and swift. The icon is widely used and looks in all Apps the same but I could not figure out how to use it.

[image]

Comment: if you need that arrow for tableview cell you can use `cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator`

Answer (score 1):

You could find [SF Symbol](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/), if you are using iOS 13+. 
All symbols you could find [here](https://sfsymbols.com/).

Answer (score 1):

there is no actual way to use this asset anywhere you want to, tho if you want to use it in tableview cell you can set

```
cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

or via Storyboards in cells attribute inspector:

[image]